# Macro in Excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the below macro for extracting data in excel 2013 now i have shifted to excel 2016. In excel 2016 the macro is not working.

```
Sub simpleXlsMerger()


    Dim bookList As Workbook

    Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("path")

    Set filesObj = dirObj.Files

    For Each everyObj In filesObj

    Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

    Range("A2:IV" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

    Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    bookList.Close

    Next

End Sub
```

Can someone help me resolving this issue

Comment: "not working" is not a very useful description of your problem.

Comment: Macro is not running actually to say

Comment: What happens when you try to run it ?

Comment: It is not displaying any results and even it is not throwing any error

Comment: if you put a msgbox call  in there does it show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub simpleXlsMerger()


    Dim bookList As Workbook

    Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("path")

    Set filesObj = dirObj.Files

    For Each everyObj In filesObj

       Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

       'EDIT
       With bookList.Sheets(1)
          .Range("A2:IV" & .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy _
             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
       End With
       '/EDIT

       bookList.Close False

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: this is running but not fetching any data

Comment: So maybe your data isn't on the first sheet?  Or you're not opening the files you expect?  Try putting a break on the "copy" line and take a look at the files as it goes through the loop.

Comment: I kept break point and checked, it is taking to file where data is existed and i can see the data